# "An error has occured in the script on this page" when opening a webpage in my C# program

Tags: c#

I am opening up a website www.odds.com.au from within my C# program (wirtten using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM, Microsoft .NET FrameworkVersion 3.5 SP1) and the following error appears when the website opens:

---

An error has occured in the script on this page
Line:  221
Char:  3
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code:  0
URL:   http://www.odds.com.au/javascripts/odds.js?1320019370
Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?

---

My xaml.cs code is:

```
private void NavigateToUrl(string Url)
{

    wbMain.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.odds.com.au", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

}
```

I have searched the internet and cannot find a definite answer. If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I think the error is inside javascript http://www.odds.com.au/javascripts/odds.js?1320019370. It has nothing to do with your code. However I do not see this error when view the same page with Chrome. You may want to disable script errors:

```
wbMain.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  Although the method ScriptErrorsSuppressed is not available for me in C#.

Comment: Just wanna say... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse [your JavaScript](http://www.odds.com.au/javascripts/odds.js?1320019370) with a [popular lint utility](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php), you will see multiple warnings. One or more of these issues may be triggering the script error that you're seeing.

In addition, the Chrome JavaScript console reports that *eventLayer.X* and *eventLayer.Y* are broken and deprecated in WebKit.

Comment: Thanks.  I am assuming I cant do anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the script error message

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```